# Pandas: combination with highest coverage

Tags: python, pandas

In a supermarket I selected 30 products on which we want to run an analysis. I want to see which 12 of them give me the widest coverage of clients (on a specific date, no time involved).

This means that I have 30!/(12!(30-12)!) = 86493225 combinations of products

My pandas dataframe of clients purchases:

| Client | Product |
| --- | --- |
| A | Banana |
| B | Apple |
| B | Banana |
| C | Water |
| ... |  |

now I could iterate to see the combination of highest client count, creating them all first with itertools

```
comb = set(itertools.combinations([banana,...], 12))
d = {}
for i in comb:
    d[i] = df[df.product.isin(i)].Client.nunique()
```

but this will take a spectacular amount of time.

do you guys see any better way to count this out?

please note that I do not want to find the combination of 12 most common products, but the combination that will yield the most clients (possibly the same but not necessarily, as 2 products not individually common may yield more clients if the 2 groups don't overlap much).

any thoughts?

thank you

Comment: *not individually common may yield more clients* - how a product that yield more clients not be common?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if the 2 groups don't overlap much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) and it is NP-hard. That link shows a greedy algorithm which provides an approximate solution: at each step add the product with the most new clients.

Comment: hi @Jeff thanks a lot for your reply. now I understand much better the issue, thanks a lot for sharing. now I can see why I could not find a way to formulate more efficiently the problem. a greedy solution may indeed be the best one when i don't have the time to wait for all the combinations. thank you